# using WebP images in outlook email

Tags: html, email, outlook, webp

I am working on email template and looking for a workaround to support webp in outlook emails. is there a way we can get non webp image from google? or convert webp image to jpeg on the fly using some api call?

Comment: I have a web app which sends emails containing webp images. In Outlook they are being displayed correctly, but not in GMail -_- so, Outlook should not have problem displaying webp images